# Is there a shouldOverrideUrlLoading in GeckoView?

Tags: java, android, firefox, gecko, geckoview

I am very familiar with using the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method in Android WebView and have used it in a few projects.
I have a new project that requires Mozilla's GeckoView instead of the standard WebView, but I can't seem to find a method to override urls (to prevent a user from following certain links off of the initially-loaded website). Does any method like that exist?

I've embedded GeckoView into my project with these instructions: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView and the websites render great.

The Android WebView code I'm trying to emulate looks like this:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (url.startsWith("https://www.example.com/")) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Is there any similar method in GeckoView?

Comment: if it has `setWebViewClient` method, create class that extends `WebViewClient` and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, @CagriYalcin! The code example was something I pulled from an old project that as using the standard Android WebView. I'm looking for the GeckView way of doing things.

Comment: So check [this](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android/issues/2911) out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is under [navigationDelegate#OnLoadRequest](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.html#onLoadRequest-org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession-org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.LoadRequest-)

```
private fun createNavigationDelegate() = object : GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate {
    override fun onLoadRequest(session: GeckoSession, request: GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.LoadRequest): GeckoResult<AllowOrDeny> {
        return if (request.uri.startsWith("https://www.example.com/")) {
            GeckoResult.fromValue(AllowOrDeny.DENY)
        } else {
            GeckoResult.fromValue(AllowOrDeny.ALLOW)
        }
    }
}

private fun setupGeckoView() {
    geckoView = findViewById(R.id.geckoview)
    val runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this)
    geckoSession.open(runtime)
    geckoView.setSession(geckoSession)
    geckoSession.loadUri(INITIAL_URL)
    geckoSession.navigationDelegate = createNavigationDelegate()
}
```

If you have any other questions you can also open an issue on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mozilla/geckoview). Another project that you may be interested in is [Mozilla Android Components](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components).